# WPF SolidColorBrush bind to another StaticResource

Tags: wpf

I have question about SolidColorBrush.

I have Resource:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Accent3" Color="#0093DD"/>
```

And I would like to bind another resource to this one like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource Accent3}}" />
```

Both of them are in same file, `AccentColorBrush` is below `Accent3`.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a color and then bind it to both your colorbrush...something like this:

```
<Color x:Key="YourColor">#0093DD</Color>


<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Accent3" Color="{StaticResource YourColor}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource YourColor}" />
```